# How to open non text files in Cygwin?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, cygwin

I am trying to open image files, pdf files and music files using Cygwin, a terminal that provides Linux functionality in Windows.  So far I have not successfully executed a command that would accomplish what I want.  I can only open text files at this moment using vim text editor.

Edit: Thanks for the comments.  I am looking to open files using appropriate windows applications.  Also, I do not know how I can figure out whether XServer is already installed and why would I need XServer to resolve my issue in the first place.

Comment: Images and PDF are graphical files, do you have an X Server installed? You'll need one to launch these files from terminal.

Comment: First, you need to decide _what program_ you want to open them with, a Windows one or a Cygwin/X one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a file from Cygwin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577595/open-a-file-from-cygwin)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `cygstart` utility, e.g.,

```
cygstart foo.bmp
```

will open up the image file in Paint.

It’s in the `cygutils` package, which I believe is installed by default. It has a [man page](http://www.fiveanddime.net/cygwin-man-pages/usr/share/man/man1/cygstart.1.html) that shows that you can use it to open URLs in your browser, among other things.